# Ansible 2.5.5 - before attribute in 'replace' module not working

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-2.x, regexp-replace

I'm trying to replace only the first occurrence after a specific string. However, ansible would always match all occurrences. Here's the file:

Here's my ansible task:

```
    - name: Update minPoolSize for CWTxDataSource dataSource
      replace:
        dest: "{{ op_db_path }}"
        after: ".*CWTxDataSourceXA"
        regexp: "^.*minPoolSize=.*$"
        replace: '        <connectionManager maxPoolSize="750" minPoolSize="20" />'
        backup: yes
```

```
    <dataSource jndiName="CWTxDataSource">
        <connectionManager maxPoolSize="750" minPoolSize="1" />
    </dataSource>

    <dataSource jndiName="UMDataSource">
        <connectionManager maxPoolSize="750" minPoolSize="1" />
    </dataSource>
```

in the above sample both `connectionManager` tags would get updated which is not the desired behavior? How can I update my `regexp` to only update first match?? I tried the `before` option in `replace` module as a workaround but that didn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: the real answer to this is to use [`xml:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/xml_module.html) that was designed for working with structured data. That said, have you already tried using [`before:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-before) in order to further confine its search space?

Comment: I'll give `xml` a try, thanks! yeah about the `before` option.

Comment: For `xml` it has a dependency on `lxml` pip module on target vms which's not optimal to maintain for my case: `"msg": "The xml ansible module requires the lxml python library installed on the managed machine"`

Comment: Then I'd guess you have two smelly options: [`slurp:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) (or `fetch:`) the file to the control node, mutate it using `xml:` as designed, then push it back to the managed node; or read the file into memory, strip the newlines so the pattern is `CWTxDataSource"(.+?) minPoolSize="1"`  and patch it in that way

Comment: thanks for responding! I see, I mean if the regexp just works on matching the first occurrence, I'd just use that but couldn't get it to only match the first occurrence.

Comment: Maybe `\A((?:(?!.*\bminPoolSize=).*\n)*\s*).*minPoolSize=.*` and in the replacement start with group 1 plus the string you want in the replacement. https://regex101.com/r/DSYwa9/1

Comment: "in the replacement start with group 1",  can you type that out? Also, can you explain a lil on how the regex work? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following line in ansible docs:

```
# Prior to Ansible 2.7.10, using before and after in combination did the opposite of what was intended.
```

so in order for me to use `after` `before` as a workaround I had to reverse their values:

```
    - name: Update minPoolSize for CWTxDataSource dataSource
      # after / before values are reversed in ansible < 2.7
      replace:
        path: "{{ op_db_path }}"
        before: 'jndiName="CWTxDataSource"'
        after: "</dataSource>"
        regexp: 'minPoolSize="\d+"'
        replace: 'minPoolSize="{{ CWTxDS_minPoolSize }}"'
```

notice the `after` `before` values don't really make sense but it works!